# Stream audio BlackBerry app

Tags: blackberry, audio-streaming, blackberry-simulator

i'm new in BB develop.
I need to stream audio in BB app. 
It's a simple webradio (very simple).

I tried this code:

```
Player p = javax.microedition.media.Manager.createPlayer("rtsp://....");
p.realize();
VolumeControl volume = (VolumeControl)p.getControl("VolumeControl");
volume.setLevel(30);
p.prefetch();
p.start();
```

Don't work !!! (tried in simulator) 
In this project I use BlackBerry JRE 7.0.0.

Comment: you want to play the online audio?

Comment: yes. It's a rtsp:// or shoutcast link.

Answer (score 2):

There are some issues I've found:

- rstp link doesn't work on simulator
- rstp probably works only appending  ";interface=wifi" on connection string
- rtsp is supported from BB JRE 4.3.0+
- check related threads on stackoverflow, there are a lot of information on your issue

BTW, try your code in a physical device and let us know if it works! :)

HTH